# background transition on button hover problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the background image transition smoothly when I hover over my buttons. I have tried looking for a way in many answered posts but I couldn't apply none of those to my code. 
I understand that I need to use J Query but I can't get it to work either.
Current code without J Query trials and errors:
http://jsfiddle.net/6YEAG/26/

```js
        function SwapInst()
        {
            document.getElementById("BG").style.backgroundImage = "url(/Images/Instruments.jpg)";
        }
```

```css
.Button
{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Button:hover
{
    background: rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 13px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <body class="body" id ="BG" style="height: 645px; background-image:url(/Images/Menu.jpg); background-size:auto;">
  <div style="font-size: 25px; color: black; text-align:center;" id ="MainHeader">
    <br />
    <h1> RED INSTRUMENTS </h1>
    <h2> Instruments and parts shop </h2>
  </div> 
  <div style="font-size: 30px; color: black; text-align: center;">
           <br />
           <br />
           <br />
            <input class="Button" onmouseover="SwapInst()" id="InstButton" type="button" value="Our Instruments" />
            <input class="Button" id="PartsButton" type="button" value="Our Parts" />
            <input class="Button" id="ContactButton" type="button" value="Contact us" />
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You do not need jQuery for this. What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Ohhhhhh.. Well I have the egg on my face.

Comment: My problem is that I can't figure out how to make a smooth transition on the body triggered by a button. I figured I needed to use CSS and JQuery for this because I couldn't find other ways and because of my inexperience with them.

Answer (score 2):

Button Background change perfectly with Jquery.
Demo(Live Example):-

https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/dmtz34ma/1/

Html:-

```
<body class="body" id ="BG" style="height: 645px;">
  <div style="font-size: 25px; color: black; text-align:center;" id ="MainHeader">
    <br />
    <h1> RED INSTRUMENTS </h1>
    <h2> Instruments and parts shop </h2>
  </div> 
  <div style="font-size: 30px; color: black; text-align: center;">
           <br />
           <br />
           <br />
            <input class="Button"  id="InstButton" type="button" value="Our Instruments" />
            <input class="Button" id="PartsButton" type="button" value="Our Parts" />
            <input class="Button" id="ContactButton" type="button" value="Contact us" />
  </div>
  </body>
```

Script:-

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#InstButton").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
           $("#BG").parent().css('background-color', 'red');
          // $("#BG..parent().css('background-image', "url('/ Put Your Web Link Here /')");")
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
           $("#BG").parent().css('background-color', 'White');
        }
    });
     $("#PartsButton").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
           $("#BG").parent().css('background-color', 'green');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
           $("#BG").parent().css('background-color', 'White');
        }
    });
     $("#ContactButton").on({
        mouseenter: function() {
           $("#BG").parent().css('background-color', 'blue');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
           $("#BG").parent().css('background-color', 'White');
        }
    });

});
```

CSS:-

```
.Button
{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Button:hover
{
    background: rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 13px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This work Perfectly using jquery

Hope its work !!

Comment: Thank you, it does work but this way to change backgrounds is without a transition. Thank you very much for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using css property transition?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

```
.Button
{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.Button:hover
{
    transition: banckground 1s rgba(15, 0, 0, 0.3)
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    border: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 13px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, couldn't get it to work as I need the background of the body to transition rather than the button's.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.button-array {
  text-align: center;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  }

.button {
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center
  align-self: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s
  }

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/3029ua0.jpg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="button-array">
  <div class="button">
    Our Instruments
    </div>
 <div class="button">
    Our Parts
    </div>
  <div class="button">
    Contact Us
    </div>
  </div>
```

You should look at CSS to do this for you, as it is easier to control and change when you need to. I used the `flex` class to create my alignment, and the `:hover` class to create the effect. You could also do this with an image background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use opacity for this, but opacity on the body would render all the page invisible.

I have used a pseudo element for this purpose.

Since this is a snippet, setting an id on body is not posible (or at least I don't know how to do it), so getting to the body is a little bit more difficult:

```js
let test = document.getElementById('test');
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
test.addEventListener("mouseenter",function(){
    body.className = 'active';
});
test.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
    body.className = '';
});
```

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);  
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  z-index: -1;
}

body.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

#test {
   width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

u may use css3 transition property like..

```
.Button
{
    /*ur code*/
    .......
    transition:all 0.8s;
}
.Button:hover
{
    /*ur code*/
    .......
    background-image: url(http://i66.tinypic.com/3029ua0.jpg);
}
```

Comment: this method changes the background image of the button rather than the body